# Excel Reports By Date with PivotTable

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a table with data that runs through the year. It's a record of sales.
I would like to have some sort of report that I can print off for clients or
vendors or whatever.

I like the pivot table concept, but I can't seem to filter by date and show the date in the resulting report. It seems odd to me that you cannot, say input
a date range and return a report that has all the entries within the range with
the date of the entry next to them.

To be clear, the question is: Is there a way to have a PivotTable filter by date and also show the date in the report?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to filter on a field and have field show up in the pivot table as well.

1. The first suggestion is You will find out that even a column only appear in the Row Label, you will see a small button besides the Cell "Row Labels", which is actually a filter.
2. Drag and Drop desired field to FILTERS group. Rename Field Name (can add a blank space to the end) Then, drag and drop same field to the other desired location, example VALUES. 
   You'll see it is retained in the filter set.
3. The other option is to insert a slicer. More a graphic filter that might work well for you.

[image]